# Admin Blank Page with Working Front-End After Updating to Wordpress 4.6

Tags: wp-admin, fatal-error

Trying to open my website admin `mywebsite.com/wp-admin` it giving me `internal server error 500`

The website working fine from the front end.

How can I access my admin and how to solve this issue?

Comment: So I understand, are you posting a question but also answering it at the same time? If so, your answer should be posted seperately.

Comment: You accidentally removed your question along with it. May you also restore just the question again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging this problem, I found this error in the PHP error log located at `public_html/mywebsite/wp-admin/error_log`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_raise_memory_limit() in /home/example/public_html/mywebsite/wp-admin/admin.php on line 141
```

This function `wp_raise_memory_limit()` should be defined in `wp-includes/functions.php` but it is not defined in my case due to an unsuccessful update by Wordpress.

**So Solution:** Do a [manual update for wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update) as I did the following:

- I downloaded the latest version of wordpress from wordpress.org
- I replaced all files and folders of my site except `wp-config.php` file and `wp-content` folder
- I opened my site url, it requested a database update

I pressed on update database and the problem resolved :)

Comment: Glad that you were able to solve your own question. Be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer after two days.